# How to run a program on GCP without hangup?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, nohup

I am trying to run a python3 program continuously on GCP. What is the best way to do this?

So far I have tried using a google compute engine virtual machine running Debian linux. I used nohup but it still hangs up when the ssh connection is broken.

What other ways could I try to run the program through the vm? Are there better alternatives using GCP to run the program continuously?

Comment: Please include code examples of what you've tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What your code is doing? Can it restart easily on failure?

Answer (score 0):

Python's installation depend on different operating systems, documentation [1] could help you to run python program in Linux or in Windows without any trouble.

On the other hand, Google App Engine applications [2] are easy to create, easy to maintain, and easy to scale as your traffic and data storage needs change. With App Engine, there are no servers to maintain. You simply upload your application and very easy to operate. The documentation [3] also could be very helpful for you.

To know more about python on Google Cloud Platform, please have the documentation [4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_python

[2] https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-python3/#0

[3] https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started

[4] https://cloud.google.com/python